# Call a child method in parent component and change the DOM in the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem. If the user press the button from the `Input.js` the method `checkAll()` should called. Inside of this method the child method  should be called `checkProfilPicture()`. This works fine. But the method `checkProfilPicture()` should change a variable to false and if the variable is false - a text should appear return `( { isPreview === false ?? ... } )`. Unfortunately this part isn't working.

So how could I appear the text when the method `checkProfilPicture()` is called`?

Childcomponent
*Profilepic.js* (Edit)

```
   import React, { useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, } from "react";
import { Pic } from "./Pic.js";

function  Profilepic (props, ref) {
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);
  const [isPreview, setIsPreview] = useState(true);

  const fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    try {
      console.log(event.target.files[0]);
      if (event.target.files[0].size > 70001680) {
        alert("File is too big!");
      } else {
        let img = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        setPreview(img);
      }
    }
    catch (err) {
    }
  };


  useImperativeHandle(ref,() => ({ 
    isPreview,
    checkProfilPicture() {
      console.log("hier bin ich")
       if(preview) {
         setIsPreview(false);
         console.log("Halloooo!!!")
         return false;
         
       }
       else {
         setIsPreview(true);
         console.log("Halloooo??")
         return true;
         
       }
    }
  
  }),
  );


  return (
    <div>
      {preview ? (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="myInput">
            <Pic preview={preview}></Pic>
          </label>
          <input
            id="myInput"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            type={"file"}
            onChange={fileSelectedHandler}
          />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="myInput">
            <i className="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
          </label>
          <input
            id="myInput"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            type={"file"}
            accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg, .jfif"
            onChange={fileSelectedHandler}
          />
        </div>
      )}
      { isPreview === false ?? 
        <div className="text-danger">Bitte lade ein Bild hoch</div>
      }
    </div>
  );
};
// eslint-disable-next-line
Profilepic = forwardRef(Profilepic);
export default Profilepic;
```

Parentcomponent *Input.js*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './Input.css';
import Profilepic from './Profilepic';
import TagsInput from '../../components/tagsInput/TagsInput'



const Input = () => {

  const profilePicRef = useRef();




  const checkAll = () => {
     const pr = profilePicRef.current.checkProfilPicture()

     
  }
  
  return (

                      <Profilepic ref={profilePicRef}></Profilepic>    
                      <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={checkAll}>Speichern &amp; Weiter <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>                 

  );
}

export default Input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the variable `preview` is always `null`. Inside the `checkProfilePicture` reference function, the `if` condition will return false, hence it will trigger `setIsPreview(true)` which doesn't really change the `isPreview` variable to true. You can try changing that particular `setIsPreview` argument to false and you should see that it's really working as expected.

Try this example below:

```js
const {
  useState,
  useRef,
  forwardRef,
  useImperativeHandle,
} = React;

const Profilepic = forwardRef(function(props, ref) {

  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);
  const [isPreview, setIsPreview] = useState(true);
  
  useImperativeHandle(ref,() => ({ 
    isPreview,
    checkProfilPicture() {
      console.log("triggered")
       if(preview) {
         setIsPreview(true);
         console.log("Setting isPreview to true");
         return false;
         
       }
       else {
         setIsPreview(false);
         console.log("Setting isPreview to false");
         return true;
         
       }
    }
  
  }));
  
  return (
    <strong>{isPreview.toString()}</strong>
  )

});

function Input() {
  const profilePicRef = useRef();
  
  const checkAll = () => {
     const pr = profilePicRef.current.checkProfilPicture();
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Profilepic ref={profilePicRef}></Profilepic> 
      <button
        onClick={checkAll}>
        Speichern &amp; Weiter
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Input />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**UPDATE: 4/17/2021**

In response to your problem regarding the rendering of the expression:

```
{ isPreview === false ?? 
  <div className="text-danger">Bitte lade ein Bild hoch</div>
}
```

This actually renders the `false` value since the operator `??` is called [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). As described in the docs:

> The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that
> returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is
> [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) or [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

Since `isPreview` is a false value and not `null` or `undefined`, then it will definitely render `false`. You can change the `isPreview` default value to `null` to see it properly.

The snippet below demonstrates how the `??` operator behaves:

```js
console.log(false ?? 'shows false!');
console.log(true ?? 'shows true!');
console.log(null ?? 'shows null');
console.log(undefined ?? 'shows undefined');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry for the inconvenience, I have removed one more method which sets preview to non-zero. And if preview is null after all, this should output the text. However, the text is not output.

Comment: It shows me true and false correctly. But what it does not show me is the if-condition. It simply does not do that. `{ isPreview === false ?? 
        <div className="text-danger">Bitte lade ein Bild hoch</div>`
      }